# Run custom command on remote Linux machine from windows machine using batch file

Tags: linux, windows, batch-file

I want to run a custom command on remote Linux machine from my windows machine using batch file. The custom command returns integer value, which will be further used by batch file. How can I achieve this?

Right now, I am invoking `winscp` from batch file and writing the output of command from `winscp` to a file remotely then using `get` command of `winscp`, I am downloading that file into my windows machine. After that I am reading that file from batch file. Okay but very long process.

My aim is to get the output of command available to batch script, so that value can be used further in batch file.

Comment: Because your question doesn't belong here but on serverfault. If the close will gain enough votes, your question will be moved from here to serverfault and not just closed. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is plink.exe. It is a command line version of [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), and if you have PuTTy installed, then you already have plink (in same directory as PuTTy)

From Batch, this will look something like this:

```
%PATH_TO_FILE%\plink.exe -batch root@10.0.0.1 "remote command"
SET RETVAL=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF NOT ["%RETVAL"]==["0"] (
    ECHO "Remote Command failed"
) ELSE (
    ECHO "Command returned with exit code %RETVAL%
)
```

Comment: Sounds Cool..... yeah.. putty is installed on my machine...

Comment: Slav: i am using `%PATHTOPUTTY%plink.exe root@192.168.10.202 -pw test@123 -m commands.txt

ECHO This is out %ERRORLEVEL%`

In console, i am getting This is out 0, which is incorrect. I just want to assign the returned value from plink.exe to some variable, so that i can use it further.

Comment: That _is_ the return value of your last linux command. Same if you would type `echo $?` after the last linux command. Maybe what you are asking for is not the return code (error code, exit code), but you want the actual output of the command? In that case, you've got to redirect that to a file on the Windows box. `whole_plink_command_ending_in_-m_commands.txt > outFile.txt`. Then read that file into a variable: `SET /P Value<=outFile.txt`. You can now use `%Value%`. There is a way of doing it without creating a temp file using "for /f" syntax, but you lose certain control over error handling.

Comment: `SET /P Value<=outFile.txt` seems ok... but i don't have to be worried about error handling this time, in any case command has to return integer value. Can you please tell the `for /f` command.. By the way thank you for the answer.

Comment: Just a little modification in the above command. `SET /P Value=<outFile.txt` what about `for /f` command?

Comment: The syntax is this: `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('any_command') DO (SET Value=%%A)`. Replace "any_command" with the whole Plink stuff, minus the file redirect. The difference (besides inability to do error handling), is that the first method will put the first line of multi-line output in variable, while this second method would pust the last line of multi-line output in variable. Doesn't matter if your output is a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can run remote commands on a Linux machine using ssh.  You can get a command-line windows port of openssh from http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/

Then, in your batch file, you simply add:

```
ssh linuxserver command-name
```

This will return the output of command-name

For example:

```
ssh linuxserver uname
```

outputs: "Linux"

Hope this helps.

Comment: Never tried `ssh` on windows. This is quite interesting if works..